# WIX broken shortcut icon

Tags: wix

I have a simple wix setup installing an executable file and a few dlls. Everything works, except the desktop shortcut is not a regular link to the executable in C:\Program Files, but some weird registry-guid-type of link hiding the executable location. On top of that the icon for this shortcut comes from the installer folder instead of the one in the executable itself.

How can I create a regular plain old and simple shortcut to c:\program files\mycompany\myproduct.exe, instead of this fancy shortcut?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="*" Name="MyProduct" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="MyCompany" UpgradeCode="11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111">
        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
        <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />

        <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="MyCompany.Desktop.Setup" Level="1">
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
            <ComponentRef Id='ProgramMenuDir' />
        </Feature>
        <Icon Id="MyProduct.ico" SourceFile="MyProduct.ico" />

        <UI>
            <UIRef Id="WixUI_Minimal" />
            <Publish Dialog="ExitDialog"
                Control="Finish"
                Event="DoAction"
                Value="LaunchApplication">WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX = 1 and NOT Installed</Publish>
        </UI>
        <Property Id="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOXTEXT" Value="Open MyProduct now" />
        <Property Id="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALTEXT" Value="Success! MyProduct is now installed." />

        <CustomAction Id="CA_Set_WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALTEXT" Property="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALTEXT" Value="Oops! Unfortunately, the installer ran into a problem and MyProduct was not installed."/>
        <InstallUISequence>
            <Custom Action="CA_Set_WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALTEXT" After="FindRelatedProducts">Installed</Custom>
        </InstallUISequence>

        <Property Id="WixShellExecTarget" Value="[#MyProductEXE]" />
        <CustomAction Id="LaunchApplication" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="WixShellExec" Impersonate="yes" />
    </Product>

    <Fragment>
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
                <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="MyProduct">
                </Directory>
            </Directory>

            <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder" Name="Programs">
                <Directory Id="ProgramMenuDir" Name="MyProduct">
                    <Component Id="ProgramMenuDir">
                        <RemoveFolder Id='ProgramMenuDir' On='uninstall' />
                        <RegistryValue Root='HKCU' Key='Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]' Type='string' Value='' KeyPath='yes' />
                    </Component>
                </Directory>
            </Directory>

            <Directory Id="DesktopFolder" Name="Desktop" />
        </Directory>
    </Fragment>

    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
            <Component Id="MainExecutable">
                <File Id='MyProductEXE' Source='$(var.MyCompany.Desktop.TargetPath)' KeyPath='yes'>
                    <Shortcut Id="startmenuMyProduct" Directory="ProgramMenuDir" Name="MyProduct" WorkingDirectory='INSTALLDIR' Icon="MyProduct.ico" IconIndex="0"  Advertise="yes" />
                    <Shortcut Id="desktopMyProduct" Directory="DesktopFolder" Name="MyProduct" Description="MyProduct Description" WorkingDirectory='INSTALLDIR' Icon="MyProduct.ico" IconIndex="0" Advertise="yes" />
                </File>
            </Component>
            <Component Id='CommonLibrary'>
                <File Id='CommonDLL' Source='$(var.MyCompany.Desktop.TargetDir)\MyCompany.Common.dll' KeyPath='yes' />
            </Component>
            <Component Id='CSVLibrary'>
                <File Id='CSVDLL' Source='$(var.MyCompany.Desktop.TargetDir)\CsvHelper.dll' KeyPath='yes' />
            </Component>
            <Component Id='InputLibrary'>
                <File Id='WinInpDLL' Source='$(var.MyCompany.Desktop.TargetDir)\WindowsInput.dll' KeyPath='yes' />
            </Component>
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <Component Id="DesktopShortcut" Directory="APPLICATIONFOLDER" Guid="*">
            <RegistryValue Id="RegShortcutDesktop" Root="HKCU" 
                    Key="Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]" Name="DesktopSC" Value="1" 
                    Type="integer" KeyPath="yes" />
            <Shortcut Id="desktopSC" Target="[APPLICATIONFOLDER]MyCompany.Desktop.exe"
                    Directory="DesktopFolder" Name="MyProduct" 
                    Icon="MyProduct.ico" IconIndex="0"
                    WorkingDirectory="APPLICATIONFOLDER" Advertise="no"/>
        </Component>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A component reference to your DesktopShortcut component is missing from your product feature. Your ProductFeature should look like this:

```
    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="MyCompany.Desktop.Setup" Level="1">
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
        <ComponentRef Id='ProgramMenuDir' />
        <ComponentRef Id='DesktopShortcut' />
    </Feature>
```

Modify your DesktopShortcut component to this:

```
    <!--DesktopShortcut-->
<DirectoryRef Id="DesktopFolder">  
  <Component Id="DesktopShortcut" 
             Guid="GENERATE A GUID FOR THIS COMPONENT">

    <Shortcut Id="desktopSC" 
              Name="MyProduct" 
              Description="MyProduct description" 
              Target="[APPLICATIONFOLDER]MyCompany.Desktop.exe"
              Icon="MyProduct.ico">
    </Shortcut>
    <RemoveFolder Id="RemoveDesktopFolder" 
                  Directory="DesktopFolder" 
                  On="uninstall" />
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" 
                   Key="Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]" 
                   Name="installed" 
                   Type="integer" 
                   Value="1" 
                   KeyPath="yes" />
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

That should give you a plain, old and simple desktop shortcut to your application.
A few points worth mentioning:

- A RemoveFolder tag has been added. This will make sure that the desktop shortcut is also removed when the application is uninstalled.
- Make sure you generate a non-changing GUID for your DesktopShortcut component. This guarantees consistency and manageability of files during installation/uninstallation.
- Notice that there's a directory reference to the desktop folder, wrapped around the DesktopShortcut component. This will make sure that the shortcut is put in a proper place. 
  In this case, the desktop.

Hope this helps!